# Programmatically Focus on DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which allows cells to be edited. Is there a way that I can programmatically focus on a specified cell in order to begin editing?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you wanting to simply select the cell, or actually enter editing mode?

Comment: Ideally, I want to enter editing mode and have the cell's contents selected. I have tried looking for some built-in function in both DataGridView and the specific DataGridViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set current cell using

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[/*rowIndex*/].Cells[/*columnIndex*/];
```

and then begin editing

```
dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```